# How to disable child form when other child form is active in c# visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to disable only the controls of parent form onclick of a button. Like in my winform application i am loading the child form onclick of a button so i want to know that how can i just disable the controls of the form not the appearance of the parent form. Could anyone help me out please ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the child form is in `Application.OpenForms`. Something like:

```
bool IsOpen=false;
FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
foreach (Form frm in fc)
{
    if(frm.Name=="YourFormName")
        IsOpen=true;
}
if(IsOpen)
{
    //Child form is open
    btnGoToChild.Enabled=false;
}
else
{
    //Not open
    btnGoToChild.Enable=true;
}
```

For re-enabling the controls,

**Parent Form**

```
gotoChild()
{
    frmChild=new frmChild(this);
    frmChild.Show();
}
```

**Child Form**

```
frmParent ObjParent=null;
frmChild(frmParent obj)   //Constructor
{
    this.ObjParent=obj;
}
CloseForm()  //invoke this function in Form_Close
{
    if(ObjParent!=null)
        ObjParent.btnGoToChild.Enabled=true;
}
```

Change the `Modifiers` property of btnGoToChild to `public`. Then only, it will be accessible from another form.

Comment: Can you please tell me that where would i write this code ?

Comment: i am at beginner level of c# so please guide me. i have this code New form = new New();
            form.Show();
            form.Left = 190;
            form.Top = 140;
on button

Comment: You want to disable the button, right? So you will have to write this code in the `form_Load` of parent form. If you need further assistance, I am glad to help.

Comment: i want to disable only the controls not the appearance of the parent form.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Try it now. Go to debugging mode and check line by line.

Comment: it is just disabling only the button

Comment: Yes. What else do you need to disable? Just add them in the if statement block.

Comment: @SyedAliAhmed: Its a pleasure, my friend.

Comment: can you also tell me that after closing the child form how do i re enable the parent form or parent forms button. ?